# Why is the blind man in John 9 sent to the pool that means "sent"?

Tags: john

In [John 9](http://esv.to/John9), Jesus performs the miracle of healing the blind man in a rather unorthodox manner. He first creates some mud or clay out of the dirt and his saliva, then he "anoints" the man's eyes, and then he tells him to go wash in the Pool of Siloam. After Jesus gives these instructions, John goes out of his way to point out that the name of the pool means "Sent."

> Then he anointed the man's eyes with the mud and said to him, "Go, wash in the pool of Siloam" (which means Sent). So he went and washed and came back seeing.

John doesn't explain every name in his gospel. So why would he point this one out?

Comment: Mark gives us a [similar story](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/565/68), but it seems to be a different man.  The detail about the translation of the name of the pool is important and unique.  Interesting observation and question.

Comment: I would suggest re-wording the title to ask why John points that out. The way it's worded sounds like you're asking why Jesus sent him to that pool, which seems like less of an exegesis question and more of a theological question. Just my two cents.

Comment: “Jesus said, “If you hold to my teaching, you are really my disciples [you are sent by God]. Then you will know the truth, and the truth will set you free [you will see] ” (John 8:31,32)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me that 'sent' is a wordplay here that reminds the reader that Jesus is sent by the Father and that the blind man was sent by Jesus. It also seems significant that the water in this pool was used for [Sukkot (the Feast of Tabernacles)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukkot).

Daniel Wallace, in his commentary on the NET translation, notes:

> The pool’s name in Hebrew is *shiloah* from the Hebrew verb “to send.”
>   In Gen 49:10 the somewhat obscure *shiloh* was interpreted messianically
>   by later Jewish tradition, and some have seen a lexical connection
>   between the two names (although this is somewhat dubious). It is
>   known, however, that it was from the pool of Siloam that the water
>   which was poured out at the altar during the feast of Tabernacles was
>   drawn....
>
> [which is translated “sent”]: This is a parenthetical note by the
>   author. Why does he comment on the meaning of the name of the pool?
>   Here, the significance is that the Father sent the Son, and the Son
>   sent the man born blind. The name of the pool is applicable to the
>   man, but also to Jesus himself, who was sent from heaven.<sup>1</sup>

According to InterVarsity Press' *Bible Background Commentary* on the New Testament,

> It is not clear whether “Siloam” meant “sent,” but Greek teachers as
>   well as Jewish teachers from Philo to the rabbis commonly made
>   arguments based on wordplays, which were often based on fanciful
>   etymologies.
>
> Although Siloam was used as a water supply and for baptizing converts
>   to Judaism, it has more direct significance here. This was probably
>   still the last day of the Feast of Tabernacles (7:2, 37), and the
>   water of Siloam was the sacred water used for this feast (see comment
>   on 7:37–38). Here Jesus employs the ritual water (cf. 2:6; 3:5), but
>   it works only because the man is “sent.”<sup>2</sup>

Some early Church fathers made the connection concerning the wordplay as well as linking the event to the sacrament of baptism. For instance, St. Augustine wrote:

> He sent him to the pool which is called Siloam. But it was the
>   evangelist’s concern to call our attention to the name of this pool;
>   and he adds, “Which is interpreted, Sent.” You understand now who it
>   is that was sent; for had He not been sent, none of us would have been
>   set free from iniquity. Accordingly he washed his eyes in that pool
>   which is interpreted, Sent—he was baptized in Christ. If, therefore,
>   when He baptized him in a manner in Himself, He then enlightened him;
>   when He anointed Him, perhaps He made him a catechumen. In many
>   different ways indeed may the profound meaning of such a sacramental
>   act be set forth and handled; but let this suffice your Charity. You
>   have heard a great mystery.<sup>3</sup>

Concerning the word 'sent' itself, the Greek word (ἀπεσταλμένος) literally means "sent out/away."<sup>4</sup> The Hebrew word being referenced by the Greek word may refer to a "flowing out (of waters)." According to Vincent,

> The Hebrew word means *outflow* (of waters); *missio*, probably with
>   reference to the fact that the temple-mount sends forth its
>   spring-waters. Many expositors find a typical significance in the fact
>   of Christ’s working through the pool of this name. Thus Milligan and
>   Moulton, after noting the fact that the water was drawn from this pool
>   for pouring upon the altar during the Feast of Tabernacles; that it
>   was associated with the “wells of salvation” (Isa. 12:3); and that the
>   pouring out of the water symbolized the effusion of spiritual blessing
>   in the days of the Messiah, go on to say: “With the most natural
>   interest, therefore, the Evangelist observes that its very name
>   corresponds to the Messiah; and by pointing out this fact indicates to
>   us what was the object of Jesus in sending the man to these waters. In
>   this, even more distinctly than in the other particulars that we have
>   noted, Jesus, in sending the man away from Him, is keeping Himself
>   before him in everything connected with his cure. Thus, throughout the
>   whole narrative, all attention is concentrated on Jesus Himself, who
>   is the Light of the world, who was ‘sent of God’ to open blind
>   eyes.”<sup>5</sup>

It should be noted that this definition is somewhat disputed. The word in Hebrew may also only mean "sending away."<sup>6</sup>

Ultimately, the wordplay seems to be the best explanation.

**Sources**

<sup>1</sup> Biblical Studies Press, The NET Bible First Edition Notes (Biblical Studies Press, 2006), Jn 9:7.

<sup>2</sup> Craig S. Keener, The IVP Bible Background Commentary: New Testament (Downers Grove, IL: InterVarsity Press, 1993), Jn 9:7.

<sup>3</sup> Augustine of Hippo, "Lectures or Tractates on the Gospel According to St. John", trans. John Gibb and James Innes, in A Select Library of the Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers of the Christian Church, First Series, Volume VII: St. Augustin: Homilies on the Gospel of John, Homilies on the First Epistle of John, Soliloquies, ed. Philip Schaff (New York: Christian Literature Company, 1888), 245.

<sup>4</sup> William Arndt, Frederick W. Danker and Walter Bauer, A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature, 3rd ed. (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2000), 120.

<sup>5</sup> Marvin Richardson Vincent, Word Studies in the New Testament (New York: Charles Scribner’s Sons, 1887), Jn 9:7.

<sup>6</sup> Francis Brown, Samuel Rolles Driver and Charles Augustus Briggs, Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon, electronic ed. (Oak Harbor, WA: Logos Research Systems, 2000), 1019.

Answer (score 3):

These questions don't necessarily have a definitive answer. But here is a thought on this question. John chapter 9 is an EXTREMELY important chapter in the gospel of John. This particular incident was really a turning point in Jesus' ministry. The receiving of sight for the blind was a miracle reserved for the Messiah (Isa 61:1,2) This is evidenced by the fact that not one time in the OT was this miracle performed, save the temporary blindness God used to save Elijah from the Syrian army.

Curing of blindness was the signature miracle of the Messiah, and that is why the incredulity, and perhaps even fear, manifest in the religious authorities regarding this notable miracle. For a prophet to cure blindness was to say that that prophet was THE prophet. It was, to cite the Isaiah passage, not just restoring sight to the blind, but declaring the acceptable year of the LORD.

Siloam does not just mean "sent" it means gushing forth. So here the miracle of the man cured of his blindness was truly a gushing forth of God's redemption to mankind. Why here and not elsewhere? Because this miracle was carefully examined by the religious authorities, even calling the parents to verify, and was consequently an undeniable proof that Jesus was not a fraud, a man not deserving of their contempt and punishment, but of their genuflection. The miracle was a clear indication that the sent one had gushed forth into the world, and the acceptable year of the LORD was on hand.

I'll try to tidy up this response later, I am running from memory here.

Comment: In addition, John makes a point that Jesus came specifically to be light.  See John 1:4-9.  Healing this man was a clear metaphor for bringing light into the world for individual people.

Comment: +1, the connection of Sent/Gushing Forth is very critical to the story. Jesus chose this location purposefully, not just for healing but for declaration of who He was.

Answer (score 0):

That which proceeded from the lords mouth onto the ground and which as made into clay to anoint his eyes - I think is a picture of the words of Christ (the gospel to all) applied - faith comes by hearing and hearing by the word of God. In obeying the instructions to baptise himself in Siloam. I
t would be complete cleansing and typical of the Gospel to those who were born blind (spiritually). His belief in the rejected Christ causes rejection by Judaism but a life in the blessings of Christ alone who makes himself fully known

Answer (score 0):

The cleasing of the blindness with "mud" is the most strong sign reminding us that we are and of clay from the deepest of the sea, the fragile state of our physical body bringing us back to the beginning of time and God's Creation reminding us as He does everywhere in the Scriptures that His Spirit hovering over the Water or let us say flying over the waters being the He is from the beginning our GOD. The dimensions of the Realms in which he created the heavens and the dimension of spiritual Realms are His to open through The WILL Of His Spirit by opening our spiritual eyes to whom He has predestine  as destiny. His WORD on Revelation is to bring us back to  HIS beginning. See how GOD always ask " Where were you when I Created the heavens and Earth? This is the reason the sign of the blind was created to remind us that HE IS the Only GOD. Amen

Comment: Hello Gina and welcome to the site. I think the idea that the mud is an allusion to the making of Adam is a useful answer to the question. Can you please edit the answer to include some supporting references either from the scriptures or from other primary or even secondary sources to make it more compelling? For example, is "mud" the same Greek word used in the making of Adam? Also, the question asked about the significance of his being sent to the pool named "sent". Do you have an answer, from the relevant scriptures for why? "Devotional" concerns are not generally relevant.

Answer (score -1):

The water from this pool (Siloam) was gathered in a silver pitcher by the High Priest' During the Feast of Tabernacles, the high priest would pour this water over the altar with the pitcher of blood. This of course is symbolic of the water and blood that flowed from Jesus's body (The Divine tabernacle of God who is with man) for the sin and healing of all.  Silver is the metal of atonement. He made atonement on the cross as the water and blood from His sinless body poured out upon the dust of the earth to atone for the sins of the whole world. His water and blood mixed with our fleshly nature will transform us into spiritual beings recreated in His image and likeness.

When studying scripture, we must be aware that Jesus and God used the things of the earth to teach spiritual truth. Jesus mixed the "water of His mouth" (spit) with the dust of the earth making clay and placed it on the blind man's eyes. The water of Jesus' mouth represents His Word. The water of the Anointed Word mixed with our earthly nature heals our spiritual blindness. The Sent One sent one to the pool of Siloam to wash. When the blind man did as the Lord told him, he was healed. He was cleansed through the washing of the "water."  In Biblical times, they made seals out of water and dirt to seal important documents so no one could open them without the king's permission. Jesus sealed this man as His own by the water and clay.

Comment: Welcome! We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to check out the site [tour] and read how this site is a [little different](http://goo.gl/wCxRAv) than others. While this is all well and good, I don't think it explains why John goes to great lengths to point out that the name of the pool means "sent" and I am unsure what "The Sent One sent one to the pool of Siloam to wash." means.  I think it means that Jesus (the sent one) sent someone to the pool called "sent" to wash, but that does nothing to explain the significance of the name of the pool or why the name is important.

Answer (score -2):

Interesting to me today I made a connection to the use of mud on the mans eyes.
JESUS had just explained that the man had been born blind intentionally by God for His glory not because of any sin...
The miracle occurred at the pool which is symbolic of the anointing of the Holy Spirit JESUS received in water baptism.
So I saw it as a symbolic process;
The mud showing JESUS as God who intentionally covered the mans eyes with blindness.
JESUS as the Son who was 'sent' by God to heal & give sight to the blind [literal or spiritually blind].
Then the use of the water at the pool being the actual means of the opening of the eyes being washed because JESUS 'sent' the man to be cleansed as He does with the Holy Spirit in baptism.
The entire process of this miracle paints an picture of the actions of God the father, the son & the Holy Spirit.
The father God 'sent' the son JESUS who 'sent' the Holy Spirit.
It's a picture of the operation of the trinity working together in 3 steps yet as one God!
God blinded, JESUS 'sent' the man to the Holy Spirit to be washed of his blindness.
As He does with us!
I'm not saying this is the only meaning of this miracle but is certainly one way to look at it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Here we ask that you answer by starting from the text  and  [showing us your work](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/846/3555). Some of the pieces here are difficult to follow, and if you could show how these ideas arise from the passage and connect the dots a little more clearly, this would improve the answer.